# How can I avoid a specific site been saved into cache?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-cache

How can I avoid a specific site been saved into cache memory, in Google Chrome or any other browser, in order to have it always "fresh" every time I reload the page?

If it is OS related I would like to know how to do it under Mac/Linux.

Comment: Do you want the html code for your own site? Otherwise, do you want to disable caching in your browser?

Comment: @Private is it possible to disable caching just for one site?

Comment: On your browser?